# My Android program using GPS is very inaccurate

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

I have made a program using GPS and its Latitude and Longitude are about 8 miles off.

I thought it may be because I am inside but when I use google maps on my phone, it shows me at my house.

Any idea why this may be?

Code below:

```
public class Clue extends Activity {

public static double latitude;
public static double longitude;
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ll;
Location location;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.blah);

  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
  criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

  lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  ll = new MyLocationListener()}

private boolean getLoc() {
location = getLocation(); 

   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
return inCorrectPlace(params);
}


    private Location getLocation() {
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);   
  return lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
}
```

I have stripped out irrelevant code, all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the last known location is very old? Can you check the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the key mistake you're making is thinking that you can instantaneously request an accurate location fix. calling `getLastKnownLocation()` gives you a location that could be quite old. you have to first tell the phone to start to try to get a location fix. this takes time, so you receive the location update asynchronously.

what you need to do is call `requestLocationUpdates()`, then receive the updates in the `onLocationChanged()` handler in your `LocationListener` class. the location updates will not necessarily be received right away. it could take several seconds to several minutes.

see the android dev guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't really rely on `getLastKnownLocation` to be reliable. It could be out of date, inaccurate, or null.

What you should do is use `requestLocationUpdates` to actively get a fix.

As far as why google maps is fixing your location, it might be using the Network provider while you are only checking the last GPS fix.